# JavaFX8 startFullDrag() not effective

Tags: java, javafx, drag-and-drop

I want to connect two circles by drag & drop.

```
Pane p = new Pane();

Circle c1 = new Circle(5);
c1.relocate(10,10);
c1.addEventFilter(MouseEvent.DRAG_DETECTED, e -> {
    c1.startFullDrag();
    System.out.println("started");
});

Circle c2 = new Circle(5);
c2.relocate(40,40);
c2.addEventFilter(DragEvent.ANY, e -> System.out.println("any") );
c2.addEventFilter(DragEvent.DRAG_ENTERED, e -> System.out.println("entered") );

p.getChildren().addAll(c1, c2);
```

That's what I tried.
When drag&dropping from the left circle `c1` to the right circle `c2`, the `DRAG_DETECTED` Event will work.
But the `DragEvent.ANY` or `DragEvent.DRAG_ENTERED` will not be triggered.

I also tried consuming mouse events in `DRAG_DETECTED` but that doesn't change anything either.
I also tried using `setOnDragEntered(EventHandler)` and `addEventHandler(EventType, EventHandler)` instead of `addEventFilter(EventType, EventHandler)` but none works.

**Why does `c2` not receive any `DragEvent`s?**

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`startFullDrag()` will trigger MouseDragEvents, but not DragEvents.

replace `addEventFilter(DragEvent.DRAG_ENTERED, ... );` with `addEventFilter(MouseDragEvent.DRAG_ENTERED, ... );`